# Win Server 2012 R2. Apply security GPO to local users on a specific machine

Tags: security, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a "demo" machine which we use for providing remote access to demo software as a local user. Is there a way to hide and deny access to everything except the user folder using a GPO?